# Symbol 'cv' could not be resolved in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to config openCV in eclipse, in include path i have added

```
/usr/local/include/opencv
/usr/local/include
```

and i have used  pkg-config --libs opencv to add some library in GCC C++ Linker:

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so
...
```

in header file i included:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/eigen.hpp>
```

but when i declare

```
using namespace cv;
```

i get an error: Symbol 'cv' could not be resolved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the *linker* cannot find a symbol named `cv`.

Assuming that you have installed everything correctly, ie. that every file <sup>[1]</sup> is where it's supposed to be, it's because you haven't told the *linker* what files it should *link* against.

<sup>**Note**: Are the files listed by `pkg-config --libs opencv` actually there?</sup>

---

**SOLUTION**

1. Go to your project's properties
2. click *C/C++ Build*
3. click *Settings*
4. find *GCC C++ Linker* (under the *Tool Settings* tab)

   1. press *Libraries*
   2. Add the *OpenCV* libraries.

---

**DETAILED GUIDE**

*OpenCV* has an official guide on how to make it work with Eclipse:

- [**opencv.org** - Using OpenCV with Eclipse (plugin CDT)](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html)

Comment: I used pkg-config --libs opencv command to find libs and added them to  GCC C++ Linker, include: 
     
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so 
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so 
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so   
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so 
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so 
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so 
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so   
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so 
    /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so 
   ...
   
    
  but it can't resolve.

Comment: You are means i must add them into project's symbols?

Comment: @user3693423 yes, that is what I'm saying - add them to the project's symbols!

Comment: I have added them into libraries tab in Path and symbol config but it still error.

Comment: @user3693423 did you check to see that, as an example, `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so` really exist? Try `ls -lah /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so`

Comment: yes, i checked and it is ok, lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Th05 14 14:38 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so -> libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4

Comment: @user3693423 then you still haven't added the files to the *symbols* list in *eclipse*. did you follow the documentation? Also; you should only add them to the *symbol configuration*.

Comment: No, i have added them into libraries tab in Path and symbol config.

Comment: Roséen What can i do?

Comment: @user3693423 it should look like this when you are done -> [image](http://docs.opencv.org/_images/a10.png).

Comment: @user3693423 see the updated post, it should explain it in detail.

Comment: It is look like that [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7rfmp7bjbev09ro/Screenshot%20from%202014-06-03%2014%3A09%3A42.png)

Comment: I added them in both Setting part of C/C++ build and Path and Symbols config.

Comment: @user3693423 it should look this [**this**](http://docs.opencv.org/_images/a10.png), notice that you have a full path - that is not correct.

Comment: Ok, i have adjust into [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/59gr2k9znywybsu/Screenshot%20from%202014-06-03%2014%3A33%3A21.png), but it is still error.

Comment: @user3693423 same or different error? because what you have should work.

Comment: then you are on your own, I've explained every step neccessary for this to work; including [**giving you this guide**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html).

Comment: i have done steps follow that link. I will review again.

Answer (score 3):

You should include at first place **/usr/local/include** in GCC C++ Compiler. See the next picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should include opencv.hpp 
go to GCC C++ Compiler, go to Includes. In Include File(-l) add /usr/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp